# Python library to identify spoken numbers and characters?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there a library that can translate spoken characters/numbers to text? Most of what I have found after googling (example [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)) has the ambition of identifying words in a certain language, but I need something "dumber". It should only identify single characters/numbers and not try to interpret them as words. Preferably I would like to configure what symbols that have a meaning.

I'm curious whether it would be possible to speak out scout codes for volleyball and have a daemon translate it into written text. An example of such code would be:

```
a10SM-1A5C *12R#5C3B etc
```

The reason is that I'm a lousy typist, and I lose track of the game when having to focus on the keyboard. Between plays, the identified code could be pasted into the scouting software.

Any pointers to such a library? It does not have to be in Python, but it is the language I use the most so it would be nice if something like this existed there.

Comment: I have never used it, but https://talonvoice.com/docs/ claims to be scriptable in Python. [Blog post describing use of it](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/blog/hands-free-coding/) which says the best, newest features are in a paid-for unreleased version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add my reflections regarding [talonvoice](https://talonvoice.com/docs/) as suggested in a comment by [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler).

Overall it works surprisingly well, but one obstacles along the way (tried on linux) was that I could not figure out how to install the speech recognition engine. It turns out that one can install [AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator) in gnome and install it from there.

I cloned [knausj_talon](https://github.com/knausj85/knausj_talon) and modified knausj_talon/code/keys.py to fit my needs:

```
default_alphabet = "away home attack serve dig block set freeball receve high medium fast other quick tense super a b c d k stop".split(
" "
)

letters_string = "a*ASDBEFRHMNOQTUABCDKs"
```

I also extended:

```
default_digits = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fiftheen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty".split(" ")
numbers = [str(i) for i in range(21)]
```

I tried it together with a demo version of [Volleystation](https://volleystation.com/) and it works reasonable well. I'm pretty sure it will work with [Datavolley](https://www.dataproject.com/Products/EN/en/Volleyball/DataVolley4) as well, but since that is only supported on Windows I have not tried it.

A phrase like:

```
<four><serve><medium><minus><one><a><one><c><space><away><thirteen><receive><high><minus><one><c><eight><b><away><k><five><plus><away><ten><attack><hash><four><a><seven><a><enter>
```

Where correctly interpreted as:

```
*4SM-1A1C a13RH-1C...
```

I have yet to see how well it works in a crowded arena, but since it was just an experiment I'm quite happy with the result.